# Word for a decision you find right but others find wrong

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word, or possibly a phrase, but preferably a single word, that describes the following:

> An action/decision that is regarded as right by one but regarded as
>   wrong by another.

Example:

> Even when you are certain that you are in the right, you should
>   refrain from _________'s, because you are in effect passing judgement onto
>   yourself.

Comment: I think you meant "in ***effect*** passing judgement ***on*** yourself..."?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "Passing judgment **onto yourself**" seems perfectly legit.

Comment: @A.P. - I'm not sure what it means to say you pass something onto yourself, "I received a present that I didn't like so I passed it onto myself." (??)  What do you think it means? Could you explain?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK that's ok, let me explain. First off, you can't just use it for any random sentence. When you pass something onto yourself, like judgement in this context, you are inviting ones criticism by doing something you are fully aware that they believe is wrong. It's something you expect to happen, therefore you are passing it onto yourself, whereas you could have prevented it.

Comment: Huh? You are saying that *"Judgement is something you expect to happen, therefore you are passing judgement onto yourself, whereas you could have prevented judgement."*  I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I was talking about passing judgment "onto someone", with the meaning being identical to "on someone". It *is* used (https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=pass+judgment+onto&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZN0YVq6vEIL8UN_9p-AC#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22pass+judgment+onto%22), but the more I think of it, the more I conclude it's not entirely grammatical, it seems. "On" or "upon" should be used.

Comment: You could have prevented the criticism by not doing that thing which you thought was right, but instead you did, and you did it knowing well that this other person thought it was wrong. And because you knew this, you in a sense invited the criticism, or you indirectly passed it onto yourself.

Comment: Romans 14:22 - Blessed is the one who has no reason to pass judgment on himself for what he approves.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm writing an essay on this concept, I'll send it to you if you'd like. ;)

Comment: @A.P. (A) That seems to be different from the meaning that Michel Rader intends (B) You are way out on a limb. Look at this ngram ---> https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pass+judgement+on%2Cpass+judgement+onto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpass%20judgement%20on%3B%2Cc0 --->  No-one in the history of publishing has used the expression "pass judgment onto".

Comment: lol well I just showed you that was wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRader - The quote from Romans, uses "pass judgement ***on***" not "Pass judgement ***onto***". Why are you showing us that? It just supports the case I am making.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I explained to you very clearly what it means. It comes from the ESV version, 'onto' means the same thing. What in the world?

Comment: lol why would you include "pass judgement on" in your ngram if it didn't mean the same thing?? lol who the heck are you?

Comment: @MichaelRader - (A) One of us is crazy and I don't think it's me in this instance. Where in the ESV version does it say "pass judgement ***onto***"?    (B) What are you talking about. The ngram shows that "pass judgement ***on***" is used frequently and "pass judgement ***onto***" is never used". Are you trolling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30107/discussion-between-chasly-from-uk-and-michael-rader).

Answer (score 1):

It fits, but I wouldn't use it myself:

> Even when you are certain that you are in the right, you should refrain from ***[contentiousness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contentious)***, because you are in affect passing judgement onto yourself.

Used as a noun, but defined as an adjective:

> - Causing or likely to cause an argument; controversial: a contentious issue.
> - Involving heated argument: the socio-economic plan had been the subject of contentious debate.
> - (of a person) given to provoking argument.
> - Law: relating to or involving differences between contending parties.

And if the disagreement drags on then you've got a ***[bone of contention...](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bone-of-contention)***

Comment: Doesn't work, but I do like your mention of 'bone of contention' - upvote for that :)

Comment: Doesn't work technically? Or you just don't like it? (I personally don't like it :)

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting question. It seems words from the semantic domain related to "judgment" might fit the bill.

How about *you should refrain from **value judgments** because you are in effect passing judgment onto yourself*?

A value judgment is defined as an evaluation based on personal values, rather than facts.

Might work in this context, since people are going to disagree about personal values. So a value will be "regarded as right by one but as wrong by another."

If one word is needed, a synonym to *value judgment* could be **subjectivity**.

Comment: Well reasoned ...

Answer (score 0):

It could be a

- ***controversial***
- ***arguable***
- ***questionable***

or

- ***despotic***

decision.

Comment: No, I'm sorry these are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @MichaelRader Can you post an example?

Comment: (-1) None of those are actions. They are adjectives.

Comment: Combined with `decision` they are all actions

Comment: Is a decision an action?   "*I decided to run*" doesn't mean, "*I ran.*"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK What's wrong with `you should refrain from controversial decisions`?

Comment: Haha! I read that as "What's wrong with you?"  :-) Seriously though,  the  tag is 'single-word' and, at the last count, I made 'controversial decisions' two words.

Comment: You forgot **polemical** in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

*Even when you are certain that you are in the right, you should
refrain from **pertinaciousness**, because you are in effect passing judgement onto
yourself.*

> pertinacious: adhering resolutely to an opinion, purpose, or design ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pertinacious))

Answer (score -2):

How about Minority:

When it came what to do with the surplus, the city commissioner was in the minority.

How about Dissensus:

When it came to what to do with the surplus, the city commissioner was in Dissensus.

Comment: You are way off my friend. Not even sure that you read the question.

Answer (score -2):

An autonomous ethical decision

Ａｕｔｏｎｏｍｏｕｓ - Independent, self.

Ｅｔｈｉｃａｌ - What's right or wrong.

Comment: I think your keyboard has diarrhea.

Comment: lol. The box drawing looked good while editing in the text box but as soon as it posted the text wrapping and line widths just messed it all up. The struggles of unicode.

Comment: to make it a singular word instead descriptive phrase simply use autonomy - state of being autonmous, self government.

Comment: How does 'autonomy' convey an action/decision that is regarded as right by one but regarded as wrong by another?